# Upper bound on $\#\{p \leq B :\#E(\mathbb{F}_p) \equiv a \mod b\}$ for large $b$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be a fixed elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$. Is there a good upper bound on $\#\{p \leq B :\#E(\mathbb{F}_p) \equiv a \mod b\}$ when $b$ is large (maybe around $\sqrt{B}$)? I don't mind assumption of conjectures such as the Riemann Hypothesis if that's needed at all.

I'm looking for something like the Brun-Titchmarsh inequality for $\#\{p \leq B :\#\mathbb{G}_a(\mathbb{F}_p) \equiv a \mod b\}$, which basically gives the upper bound of $O(\frac{B}{\phi(b)\log(B/b)})$. I would expect something similar for my question, that we would get something like $O(C(a,b)\frac{B}{\log{B}})$, where $C(a,b)$ is some proportion of elements in some Galois group.

Comment: Let $\rho_b\colon G_{\mathbb Q}\to \mathrm{GL}(E[b])\simeq \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb Z/b\mathbb Z)$
be the mod $b$ Galois representation arising from the action of $G_{\mathbb Q}$ on the $b$-torsion points of $E$. Then your set is exactly $\{p \le B : \det(1-\rho_b(\mathrm{Frob}_p)) = a\}$ (except for finitely many primes $p$ of bad reduction). Let
$C(a, b) = \frac{\#\{g\in \mathrm{Im}(\rho_b) : \det(1-\rho_b(g)) = a\}}{\#\mathrm{Im}(\rho_b)}$.
Then, by the Chebotarev density theorem, we have 
$\{p \le B : \det(1-\rho_b(\mathrm{Frob}_p)) = a\} \sim C(a, b)\frac{B}{\log B}$
as $B\to \infty$.

Comment: So perhaps you can use an explicit version of the Chebotarev density theorem to get a bound for small $B$? On the other hand, when $B$ is too small, you have to contend with the Hasse bound $|p + 1-\#E(\mathbb F_p)| < 2\sqrt p$. If  $\#E(\mathbb F_p) = a + bn$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$, then by the Hasse bound, $(\sqrt{a+bn}-1)^2 < p < (\sqrt{a+bn}+1)^2$. If you take $B\approx b^2$, then the largest $n$ can be is about $b$, and so maybe that gives an additional constraint?

Comment: The Chebotarev density theorem does indeed give the bound I want as $B$ tends to infinity. However, just like in the context of the Brun-Titchmarsh theorem, the Chebotarev density theorem gives a really bad bound when $b$ is large. For example, assuming the GRH, it would still give an error term of $B^{1/2}\log B$ even if $b = B/10$. Furthermore, around $b=B^{1/2}$ is exactly when the Brun-Titchmarsh theorem becomes a stronger bound than the one coming from Chebotarev.

Comment: There are generalizations of Brun-Titchmarsh to the context of Chebotarev density theorem, but none of them seem strong enough yet. However, I would be more hopeful for this specific case, since it's much more similar to the original Brun-Titchmarsh.